# How to write journal in Latex using Elsevier class files

Tags: elsarticle, journal-publishing

I am writing a journal in latex using the template files provided from Elsevier website.

Here is the starting code:

```
\documentclass{jfm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\title{Satisfying Continuity Equation for Incompressible Flows to Machine    Zero}

\author
{
Shashank Mishra\aff{1}
\corresp{\email{mishrash@mail.uc.edu}},
\and 
Shabaan Abdallah\aff{1}
}

\affiliation
{
\aff{1}
Department of Aerospace Engineering and Engineering Mechanics, University of       Cincinnati, Cincinnati, Ohio, 45220
}

\maketitle
```

When I compile this, it says on the top "this draft is created using the Latex style file belonging to the journal of fluid mechanics".

Is this fine or do I need to somehow remove this?

Comment: If your article belongs to Elsevier, your apt class and templates would be [elsarticle](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions)

Comment: And, don't think that `jfm` belongs to Elsevier, but it should be Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Hi thanks. The thing is I am using journal file latex template from ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle. These files do not compile properly and there is issue with adding references. I checked for the solution and installed biber but since I am new, I could not figure it out. still trying

Comment: It would be worth if you provide a [MWE](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-minxampl.html) with the `elsarticle` template, so that we can look into it.

Comment: The `elsarticle` bundle itself contains `elsarticle-template-num.tex` and `elsarticle-template-harv.tex` for numbered and harvard style references.  You can use either of them according to your requirements.  The bundle also contains an excellent documentation as well (elsdoc.pdf), which clearly explains the usage of the template.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense: you claim to use elsarticle, but the example clearly states you're using jfm.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[prodtf]{jfm}
```

but I suppose that it will not work. A lot of packages are required which may be only present for the publisher when it runs your document.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. 
The thing is I am using journal file latex template from      http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle. 

These files do not compile properly and there is issue with adding references. I checked for the solution and installed biber but since I am new, I could not figure it out. 
still trying

Comment: Using the `alsarticle.cls` is far different from using the class `jfm.cls`. Edit your example so that we can see what you really tried!